# NSIS ShellExecAsUser plugin not found

Tags: nsis

I'd like to use the [ShellExecAsUser plugin](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ShellExecAsUser_plug-in) with NSIS 3.08.

I have placed the plugin .dll Unicode version into the "Plugins\x86-unicode" and the ANSI version into the "Plugins\x86-ansi" directory.

When I do

```
!insertmacro ShellExecAsUser::ShellExecAsUser 'open' '$INSTDIR\bin\program.exe' '' '' ''
```

... then makensis produces the following error:

```
!insertmacro: macro named "ShellExecAsUser::ShellExecAsUser" not
found!
```

What do I need to do to make the plugin work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug-ins don't use `!insertmacro`.

Just call it directly:

```
ShellExecAsUser::ShellExecAsUser "" cmd.exe "/k echo Hello" SW_SHOWDEFAULT
```